# Google VR SDK 360 Video

Tags: android, virtual-reality

Recently, I'm doing some research work on **Google VR SDK** on android platform. I fetch the SDK from github https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk. It contains several aar libraries, such as common, commonwidget, etc.

1. Does anyone know where can I download the source code of these libraries?
2. Why the VR video has no changes in Y axis after invoking the method `onPanningEvent(float translationPixelX, float translationPixelY)` in **VrWidgetRenderer** class file? X axis is Okay.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk/issues/345) post on the Google VR SDK git issues might answer your question.

My answer to your question is : No, i don't think Google will give its source code.

Regards

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)